# Change precision of values in matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to change number of values after comma in matrix:

```
95%     CI 
lower   upper     mean
1,0345  1,4567    1,0987
1,0965  1,2345    1,3458
3,4958  4,5969    2,3094
...
```

I need to reduce numbers after to comma up to 2, e.g. 1,23.
I was trying sprint with `%02f` but it didn't work.
Could you help me please.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: If they are character vectors, you can use `substr(df$lower, 1, 3)`.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Returns an `Error in tabletext$lower : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: I just showed that as an example assuming you had a data frame with that column lower. I can't tell from what you posted how you stored the above table.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Convert `1,0345` to `1,03`? I don't understand the placement of the commas.

Comment: Yes, that is what i want

Comment: The problem here is that the question does not say what the object corresponding to the data is. I assumed it is a data frame with some column names. Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substr` will work:

```
> matrix(c("1,0345","1,4567","1,0987","1,0965","1,2345","1,3458"),2,3)
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
[1,] "1,0345" "1,0987" "1,2345"
[2,] "1,4567" "1,0965" "1,3458"

> substr(matrix(c("1,0345","1,4567","1,0987","1,0965","1,2345","1,3458"),2,3),1,4)
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] "1,03" "1,09" "1,23"
[2,] "1,45" "1,09" "1,34"
```